# Is the temperature different and or salinity different can lead to different colour of the water bodies?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, spectroscopy, fluid-statics

I had skimming on an article about Thermocline and Halocline.
[How can two seas not mix?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51293/how-can-two-seas-not-mix?newreg=f2bd332856bf4441bc2a6c58d913573e)
However, I am still curious on:

1. Why the effect of Thermocline and Halocline are distinguishable based on colour different?
2. Is not the substance that is dissolved in the water will give a colour in the water bodies?
3. Do the temperature different and the salinity different will change the colour of the water bodies?
4. Do we measure the effect of Thermocline and Halocline by thermal and salinity parameter also instead of based on visual appearance?

And explanation with figure would be nice. Thanks before.

Comment: Just an curiousity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know the reason for the colour difference shown in [How can two seas not mix?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51293/how-can-two-seas-not-mix) as we have no information on the composition of the water either side of the divide.

Temperature does not significantly change the colour of water in the range 0 - 50C. [This article](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~etrnsfer/water.htm) has a nice explanation of the absorption bands of water and how they shift with temperature.

I haven't been able to find any information of light absorption by saline, but my guess is that it too won't have much effect.

So I would guess the colour difference seen in the picture is the result of particulates suspended in the water rather than salinity or temperature differences.

Comment: thanks for your opinion. One of the logic alternatives that is reasonable